# Clear icon event in text input on IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

that make up a currency converter, one with the number to be converted, the other receiving the converted number.

[image]

My question is: in IE in the input field, an X appears that if clicked allows the deletion of the value. I need to know how I do it (maybe with Javascript) at the click of the X I have to delete the result received in the other input field (see image).

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify it I use c #.

Comment: Hi, may I know if you have got any chance to check [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69446543/clear-icon-event-in-text-input-on-ie/69460705#69460705)? Is it helpful to deal with the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific event handler available for the clear(X) icon. As a workaround, you can use the [mouseup event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event) to catch the change when you clear the input by clicking the clear(X) icon.

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    input1: <input type="text" id="ipt1" value="111" /><br />
    input2: <input type="text" id="ipt2" value="222" />
    <script>
            $("#ipt1").bind("mouseup", function (e) {
                var $input = $(this),
                    oldValue = $input.val();

                if (oldValue == "") return;

                // When this event is fired after clicking on the clear button
                // the value is not cleared yet. We have to wait for it.
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var newValue = $input.val();
                    if (newValue == "") {
                        $("#ipt2").val("");
                    }
                }, 1);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]